# Logstash - filter based on a dedicated time field for the last 30 days

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration, elk

I have an application that receives logs remotely from IoT devices. Those logs have timestamps from when they really happened - I process and log these logs and therefore have a specific time field `original-log-time` in my JSON logs.

So every one of my log files has the known `@timestamp` field of when this line was written to the file and an `original-log-time` field that contains the original log time.

Now I would like to only forward logs to elastic search *if* the original log time is less than 30 days in the past. The reason for this is, that logs from each day get their own index and only the last 30 indices are warm - the others are actually closed and I don't want them to be reopened.

What I am trying:

```
if [original_log_time].compareTo(ctx._source.time.plusDays(30)) <= 0 {
  elasticsearch {
     hosts => ["${ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS:?ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS environment variable is required}"]
     index => "my-logs-" + original_log_time
     user => "${ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME:}"
     password => "${ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD:}"
  }
}
```

But this leads to the following error

```
Expected one of [, #, in, not , ==, !=, <=, >=, <, >, =~, !~, and, or, xor, nand, { at line 28, column 24*(byte 512) after output if [log_index_date]"
```

I read about Logstash `ignore_older` but it looks like I can't specify which timestamp it should take into account for that check? Any smarter solution?

**UPDATE**

As I got some errors that there is neither a `compareTo`nor a `plusDays`in logstash I tried another approach I read here: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/adding-1-day-to-the-date/129168

which was a filter

```
filter {
  date {
    match => [ "log_index_date", "dd.MM.yyyy" ]
    target => "log_index_plus_thirty"
  }

  ruby {
    code => 'event.set("log_index_plus_thirty", LogStash::Timestamp.new(event.get("log_index_plus_thirty")+86400*30))'
  }
}
```

with the following if condition:

```
   if [@timestamp] <= [log_index_plus_thirty] {
      elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["${ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS:?ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS environment variable is required}"]
        index => "device-logs-" + log_index_date
        user => "${ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME:}"
        password => "${ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD:}"
      }
    }
```

but this complains at the *_plus_thirty* part of the if condition as if that variable would not exist.

Also `log_index_date` is an optional field so not sure if that leads to a problem as well?

Comment: It looks like the error is just coming from your `if` statement. Can you try `if [original_log_time] < ctx._source.time.plusDays(30) ` and see if this gets rid of the error? I don't believe there is a `compareTo()` in logstash.

Comment: yeah it seems there is also no plusDays in logstash, I tried something else and will update my question